# NSMutableArray replace content?

Tags: objective-c

I have a custom object and NSMutableArray as instance member.
I fill the array with some data after creation.
I need a method to replace the content of the array.
I tried:

```
-(void)replaceArr:(MyClass*) obj
{
 [mList removeAllObjects];
 NSMutableArray * tempArr=[obj mList];
 mList=[NSMutableArray initWithArray:tempArr];
}
```

But it is failed on

```
mList=[NSMutableArray initWithArray:tempArr];
```

Comment: you should start accept some answers by clicking on the V mark under the score in the left

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `+alloc-init`ing another `NSMutableArray`, you could also just replace the contents of this one by first removing all the objects it contains, and then adding the new ones to it:

```
- (void)replaceArr:(MyClass *)obj {
    [mList removeAllObjects];
    [mList addObjectsFromArray:[obj mList]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean `[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:tempArr];`